# Viewing Pytorch weights from a *.pth file

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, prediction, torch

I have a **.pth** file created with Pytorch with weights. How would I be able to view the weights from this file?

I tried this code to load and view but it was not working (as a newbie, I might be entirely wrong)-

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models

torch.save('weights\kharif_crops_final.pth')

models.load_state_dict(torch.load('weights\kharif_crops_final.pth'))
models.eval()
print(models)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import torch

model = torch.load('path')
print(model)
```

*(Verify and confirm)*

Comment: How can I on just CPU only?

Comment: Hiding it could be useful. As a suggestion, you could use:
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""

Answer (score 2):

```py
PATH = 'weights\kharif_crops_final.pth'
state = {'model': model.state_dict()}
torch.save(state, PATH)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH)['model'])
# print weights
for k, v in model.named_parameters():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: Name Error- 'model' is not defined.

Comment: You should have a model that needs to be saved as a pth file, otherwise you can't use torch.save.

Comment: While I simply ran it- import torch

model = torch.load('path')
print(model), it gave the tensor weights. Anyhow, how can I convert it into a CSV?